# Manual calculation of engine load

Tags: diagnostics, obd, engine-load, pid

Calculated engine load (PID $04) is determined (according to SAE J1979) by equation:

> LOAD_PCT = [current airflow] / [(peak airflow at WOT@STP as a function of rpm) *
>   (BARO/29.92) * SQRT(298/(AAT+273))]
>
> ⎯ STP = Standard Temperature and Pressure = 25 °C, 29.92 in Hg BARO,
>
> ⎯ SQRT = square root;
>
> ⎯ WOT = wide open throttle, AAT = Ambient Air Temperature and is in °C

Does "peak airflow" parameter is possible to read from ECU or does it know only by manufacturer to provide PID $04? Generally can I calculate this value manually with using of available parameters from ECU?

Comment: Read this : https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/a/17548/10976

Comment: This question don't say how to calculate peak airflow value.

Comment: “This question doesn’t say how to....”